# getting Id of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin. and designing the webpage using various elements (e.g,div ,li etc) .
There are tabs(tab1,tab2,tab3 ect) and through internal link these tabs contain several nos of fields(field1,,field2,....filed n).

Actually I want to mark the bg-color of the tab(e.g,tab2) as 'red' if there is any 'required' field  missed .
For that I have tried the following code...

```
if(!(jQuery('#admissionForm').valid())) {
    var n = $("label.error").parents("div.tab-body").index();
    console.info(n);
    var sel = "li.ui-state-default:nth-child(" + n + ")";
    console.info(sel);
    jQuery('label.error').each(function(n) {
        $("label.error").parents("div#form-wizard").children("ul.ui-tabs-nav").children(sel).children("a").css("background-color","red");
    });
}
```

The problems are

1. This code works for only one tab.
2. The .each() function takes the highest index.For example if there are error in all tabs then it marks only the 'tab3' tab not all the tabs.

So I want code which can mark the tabs. as respective error occurred as well doesn't mark the tabs which does contain any error.
Plz.. somebody help me out.
Thanx.. in advance...

Comment: for referencing tabs, are you referring them with a common id or a common class or different id altogether?

Comment: Not really sure, but I think it would make more sence to do it the other way around and iterate over the tabs and check if they contain any fields with the class .error, can't really give an example as I have no idea what the HTML structure looks like.

Comment: Could u provide the markup as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a little tricky to help you with. I'm not sure how familiar you are with the validate plugin.

You can't really do it the way you want it to, because you need to check all panels' inputs and see if they were valid or not.
The only way to differentiate that, without using the internal validation, is by using `label.error:visible` and `label.error:hidden` to see if they were valid or not. That is where your first problem lie. Since you have tabs, they are hidden even though they might be errored.
Which is why your example can only mark one tab or all tabs.

To solve this, you need to replace the current validation handler and unhighlight, so that you can do some highlighting and checking on your own.

I've arranged [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XDFd5/1/) that you can "fiddle" around with, hopefully the comments are enough to help you.

The idea is that at validation, you check which inputs were invalid, then get the parent panel and add an error class to the corresponding tab. When the user has corrected the error, or there is no error, the `unhighlight` will remove the error class from the tab.

And here's the code. Using JQuery, JQuery UI and JQuery validation plugin.

Javascript

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$("#submitForm").button();
$("#validatetabs").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("Done!");
  },
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    //Check if there are any invalid fields
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
        //Get all panels with errors
        var errorpanels = $(validator.invalidElements()).closest(".ui-tabs-panel", form);
        //Get ui tab sibling for every panel and add error
        errorpanels.each(function(){
            $(this).siblings(".ui-tabs-nav").children("li").addClass("ui-state-error");
        });
    }
  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass);

    //Get panel
    var panel = $(element).closest(".ui-tabs-panel", element.form);
    if (panel.size() > 0) {
        //Check to see if there are any more errors on this panel
        if (panel.find("." + errorClass + ":visible").size() == 0) {
            //Find matching tab for this elements panel id
            panel.siblings(".ui-tabs-nav")
              .find("a[href='#" + panel[0].id + "']")
              .parent().removeClass("ui-state-error");
          }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="validatetabs" method="get" action="">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      A required field: <input id="inp1" name="inp1" class="required" type="text"/>
    <br/>
      Another required field: <input id="inp1a" name="inp1a" class="required" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      A required field: <input id="inp2" name="inp2" class="required" type="text"/>
    <br/>
      Another required field: <input id="inp2a" name="inp2a" class="required" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      A required field: <input id="inp3" name="inp3" class="required" type="text"/>
    <br/>
      Another required field: <input id="inp3a" name="inp3a" class="required" type="text"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
      <input id="submitForm" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label, input{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}

label.error{
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: -26px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
```